# PHP how to parse JSON data double bracket without key in foreach loop

Tags: php, json

This is a REST API Output. I'm trying to access each value in foreach loop in PHP but there is no key and the double bracket is making it so much difficult for me.

Output JSON data: `{ "time":20211101, "data":" [[1630454700,0.01823,0.01823,0.01823,0.01823,5366.009589], [1630461840,0.01876,0.01877,0.01876,0.01877,5713.905167], [1630462080,0.01877,0.01877,0.01877,0.01877,1039.957378], [1630477560,0.01777,0.01776,0.01778,0.01779,1000.000000]]" }`

Comment: You can use two foreach loops

foreach($response->data as $value=>$key) {
foreach($value as $item=> $key2) {

}
}

Comment: @JamesShisiah show me an example, thank you!

Comment: Use [`json_decode($text, true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the JSON into data structures, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to figure out how the data structure looks like then read about [PHP arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and learn how to manipulate them.

Comment: @axiac lol, you think that is too easy but you are wrong. If you use ```$array = json_decode($text, true)``` and then  ```echo $array['data'];``` than you can get all numbers. If it is an array you can't echo an array.

Comment: Hmm... you are right. `$array['data']` is not an array but a string that contains a two dimensional array serialized as JSON. Use `json_decode()` to parse it into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode($text, true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the JSON into an object having the properties `time` and `data`.
The value of the `data` property is a string that is the JSON representation of a bidimensional array. Use `json_decode()` again on it to extract the array of numbers. Then use `foreach()` to iterate over the values.

```php
$text = '{ "time":20211101, "data":" [[1630454700,0.01823,0.01823,0.01823,0.01823,5366.009589], [1630461840,0.01876,0.01877,0.01876,0.01877,5713.905167], [1630462080,0.01877,0.01877,0.01877,0.01877,1039.957378], [1630477560,0.01777,0.01776,0.01778,0.01779,1000.000000]]" }';

$parsed = json_decode($text, true);
$data = json_decode($parsed['data'], true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo("| ");
    foreach ($row as $val) {
        echo("$val | ");
    }
    echo("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
| 1630454700 | 0.01823 | 0.01823 | 0.01823 | 0.01823 | 5366.009589 | 
| 1630461840 | 0.01876 | 0.01877 | 0.01876 | 0.01877 | 5713.905167 | 
| 1630462080 | 0.01877 | 0.01877 | 0.01877 | 0.01877 | 1039.957378 | 
| 1630477560 | 0.01777 | 0.01776 | 0.01778 | 0.01779 | 1000 |
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/mSbso).

Comment: Perfect, the answer that i was looking for.
Just one more question. What if the API comes with 3 ```data``` keys instead of one ```data```, i.e. ``` "data1":" [[1630454700,0.01823.......... "data2":" [[1630454700,0.01823..........., "data3":" [[1630454700,0.01823.........``` ? I tried ```json_decode($parsed, true);``` as the second ```json_decode``` but i got Warning ``` json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two **foreach** loops since that response has two arrays on that '**data**' property, assuming that the JSON response is set to a variable called **$response**:

```
foreach($response->data as $value => $key) { 
   
 foreach($value as $item => $key2) { 
    
    } 
    
  }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The whole group of numbers is considered as string not as array because of double brackets.

Comment: @Avel using json_decode before each loop